# Can preemption happen while execution is in kernel space?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

What happens when task1's execution (through syscall) is happening in kernel space & a higher priority task is launched?

Can preemption happen while current execution is in kernel space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can - subject to the kernel running on the system having been compiled with the CONFIG_PREEMPT option to allow this.

See http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/Preemption for some more details.